# File not executable.make it executable forcefully

Tags: linux, executable, chmod

I just have downloaded gmtp source to connect android mtp device to my Ubuntu Linux 10.10. But when I enter command ./configure it says permission denied and chmod 0777 ./ configure is not making it executable. On double clicking it in nautilus I found that Ubuntu gives me warning that it is downloaded from untrusted source. Is there any solution to it.please help me as I am new to Linux.

Comment: Even though you're new to Linux, you don't seem to be new to SO. Why didn't you ask this on AskUbuntu or Superuser?

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 0777 ./configure` should work. You need to own the file though, if you don't, `sudo chown yourusername configure` (you might need to do sudo `chown your_username -R .` to acquire the whole directory recursively as `.configure` might need to read other files)  or run the `chmod` command with sudo.